# Type string has no member swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.language], options: 0)
```

I am attempting to use Apple's ML Libraries for iOS and I am getting the error:

> Type 'String' has no member 'language'

What is the issue with the enums? I followed an example and cannot tell the issue.

Comment: What has this to do with Java?

Comment: That code works in latest Xcode/Swift. Did you import Foundation? What version of Xcode/Swift are you using?

Comment: @LouFranco, Xcode 9.0, Swift 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Did you try importing foundation?

```
import Foundation
```

at your file beginning