# How to correct NSLinguisticTagger function with error "Type 'String' has no member 'tokenType'" on Mac OSX (function works on iOS)?

Tags: swift

I'm working with the natural language text using Swift on Mac OSX 10.13.6 but get the error "Type 'String' has no member 'tokenType'".

To simplify, I stripped the code down and used the code from Apple's documentation with the same results. The code compiles fine on iOS 12.0 and iOS 11.4 but not with Mac OSX (10.14, 10.13, or 10.10).

```
import Foundation

struct Wordy {

    func parseWords(text: String) {
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.tokenType], options: 0)
        tagger.string = text

        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
        let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace]
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: .tokenType, options: options) { _, tokenRange, _ in
            let word = (text as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
            print(word)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line with the problem. Everything else compiles fine:

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.tokenType], options: 0)
```

So I also tried this:

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [NSLinguisticTagScheme.tokenType], options: 0)
```

But still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

I checked other answers such as [Type string has no member swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799116/type-string-has-no-member-swift) 
which recommended importing Foundation. I'm already doing that. Others suggested a change in OS version which is why I've a focus on that.

I'm using Xcode 10.5(beta) but also have the error when using Xcode 9.4.1. My mac is only using the English language, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in `enumerateTags(in:, unit:, scheme:, options:)`as it's available from IOS 11 , see here in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/2875124-enumeratetags?changes=_8)

```
import Foundation

struct Wordy {

    func parseWords(text: String) {
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.tokenType], options: 0)
        tagger.string = text

        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
        let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace]
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: .tokenType, options: options) { _, tokenRange, _ in
                let word = (text as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
                print(word)
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

            tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, scheme: .tokenType, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, sentenceRange, stop) in
                let word = (text as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
                print(word)

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sad to report, I still have the problem after making the change. My deployment target is macOS 10.13. Anything else I can try? What did I do wrong? The same error is occurring on the line where tagger is defined.

Comment: @Marcy I can't reproduce any issue except the one pointed to in this answer. Can you post an example project?

Comment: I have placed the project here https://github.com/PepperoniJoe/Wordy   A little background, the project is an exercise from Exercism.IO using TDD. So am not 100% clear why the project was set up as it is. But I've had no problems with their exercises in the past.

Comment: Matt and Sh_Khan Thank-you for your input as it triggered me to check the project settings more closely. The project had Project Format set to Xcode 3.2 compatibility and in the Build Settings the Swift Language Version was set to Swift 3. Changing those to a current version resolved the error.